# detect URL Scheme for mobile browser

Tags: javascript, php, android, ios, mobile

**How is detect URL Scheme for mobile browser via javascript or php?**

Purpose:
Mobile web page redirect to payment application, return active web browser (not default browser)

1. example.com/payment **to** payapp://page?token= 123&sender_app_schema=”googlechrome://example.com/success
2. paymentapp://pay
3. return?

googlechrome://example.com/success

firefox://open-url?url=http://example.com/success

safari://url

Comment: So, if I visit the site in safari, and then redirected to the payment app. You would like control of which browser to return me to?

Comment: yes, exactly that

Comment: What if I don't have the browser you want to use installed? There's a reason apps open links in the default browser.

Comment: You got it wrong, I want to get the "url scheme" of the browser it is currently in so we can go back

Comment: URL schemes are registered to the browser, not the OS right? Firefox doesn't respect chrome URLs for instance.